# Como ordenar um dicionário python em ordem decrescente?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Como posso ordenar esse dicionário de forma que fique em ordem decrescente:

```
 dict= {'1': array([44, 32, 56, 57, 43, 21, 36, 35, 39, 27, 23, 24, 25, 26, 31, 28, 29,
           30, 20, 22, 18, 19,  8,  1, 33,  2,  3,  4,  0,  6,  7,  9, 17, 10,
           11, 12, 50, 55, 13, 14, 15, 16, 52, 46, 45, 34, 42, 37, 40,  5, 54,
           51, 53, 48, 38, 41, 49, 47], dtype=int64), '2': array([50, 27, 39, 44, 47, 35, 28, 25, 37, 36, 29, 20, 21, 22, 13,  9, 18,
            6,  2, 14, 15, 16,  4,  7, 24, 19,  1,  5,  8, 17, 12, 11,  0,  3,
           10, 53, 49, 42, 55, 57, 45, 56, 54, 38, 23, 26, 31, 52, 51, 43, 33,
           46, 48, 40, 30, 34, 32, 41], dtype=int64), '3': array([54, 29, 40, 42, 53, 23, 31, 34, 37, 39, 38, 17, 19, 22, 12, 10, 11,
            3,  6, 13, 15,  8, 14, 16, 25, 27,  4,  5, 21,  0,  1, 18,  9,  7,
            2, 32, 28, 46, 48, 57, 56, 55, 20, 44, 33, 26, 41, 52, 24, 45, 43,
           50, 51, 49, 35, 30, 47, 36], dtype=int64), '4': array([57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41,
           40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24,
           23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,
            6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0], dtype=int64)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizei o dicionário da seguinte forma:

```
dict= {'1': [44, 32, 56, 57, 43, 21, 36, 35, 39, 27, 23, 24, 25, 26, 31, 28, 29,
           30, 20, 22, 18, 19,  8,  1, 33,  2,  3,  4,  0,  6,  7,  9, 17, 10,
           11, 12, 50, 55, 13, 14, 15, 16, 52, 46, 45, 34, 42, 37, 40,  5, 54,
           51, 53, 48, 38, 41, 49, 47], '2': [50, 27, 39, 44, 47, 35, 28, 25, 37, 36, 29, 20, 21, 22, 13,  9, 18,
            6,  2, 14, 15, 16,  4,  7, 24, 19,  1,  5,  8, 17, 12, 11,  0,  3,
           10, 53, 49, 42, 55, 57, 45, 56, 54, 38, 23, 26, 31, 52, 51, 43, 33,
           46, 48, 40, 30, 34, 32, 41]}
```

E utilizei isso aqui para ordenar..

```
{k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

Resultado:

```
{'2': [50,  27,  39,  44,  47,  35,  28,  25,  37,  36,  29,  20,  21,  22,  13,  9,  18,  6,  2,  14,  15,  16,  4,  7,  24,  19,  1,  5,  8,  17,  12,  11,  0,  3,  10,  53,  49,
  42,  55,  57,  45,  56,  54,  38,  23,  26,  31,  52,  51,  43,  33,  46,  48,  40,  30,
  34,  32,  41], 
'1': [44,  32,  56,  57,  43,  21,  36,  35,  39,  27,  23,  24,  25,
  26,  31,  28,  29,  30,  20,  22,  18,  19,  8,  1,  33,  2,  3,  4,  0,  6,  7,  9,
  17,  10,  11,  12,  50,  55,  13,  14,  15,  16,  52,  46,  45,  34,  42,  37,  40,  5,
  54,  51,  53,  48,  38,  41,  49,  47]}
```

Caso queira em ordem contrária basta colocar o reverse como **FALSE**

**EXEMPLO COM VARIAVEL JÁ CRIADA ANTERIORMENTE**

```
a = [44, 32, 56, 57, 43, 21, 36, 35, 39, 27, 23, 24, 25, 26, 31, 28, 29,
           30, 20, 22, 18, 19,  8,  1, 33,  2,  3,  4,  0,  6,  7,  9, 17, 10,
           11, 12, 50, 55, 13, 14, 15, 16, 52, 46, 45, 34, 42, 37, 40,  5, 54,
           51, 53, 48, 38, 41, 49, 47]

dict= {'1': a, '2': [50, 27, 39, 44, 47, 35, 28, 25, 37, 36, 29, 20, 21, 22, 13,  9, 18,
            6,  2, 14, 15, 16,  4,  7, 24, 19,  1,  5,  8, 17, 12, 11,  0,  3,
           10, 53, 49, 42, 55, 57, 45, 56, 54, 38, 23, 26, 31, 52, 51, 43, 33,
           46, 48, 40, 30, 34, 32, 41], '3': [54, 29, 40, 42, 53, 23, 31, 34, 37, 39, 38, 17, 19, 22, 12, 10, 11,
            3,  6, 13, 15,  8, 14, 16, 25, 27,  4,  5, 21,  0,  1, 18,  9,  7,
            2, 32, 28, 46, 48, 57, 56, 55, 20, 44, 33, 26, 41, 52, 24, 45, 43,
           50, 51, 49, 35, 30, 47, 36], '4': [57, 56, 55, 54, 53, 52, 51, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45, 44, 43, 42, 41,
           40, 39, 38, 37, 36, 35, 34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24,
           23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,  9,  8,  7,
            6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1,  0]}

{k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}
```

Comment: Estou recebendo este erro ao tentar assim: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.

Comment: não precisa colocar array([]) em cada item, deixa como eu mostrei no exemplo que montei

Comment: Tenho um problema então, porque esse dicionário retorna de uma outra parte do código e ele está me retornando desta forma. Sabe o que é possível fazer neste caso?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, é um dicionário composto por vários vetores de INT, correto? nesse caso não tem problema, a questão é, porque voce está utilizando o nome array para informar que são vetores? vou adicionar um outro exemplo na inha resposta para ver se ajuda

Comment: O problema é que eu não utilizo o nome array para informar que são vetores, isso é retornado desta forma e não entendo o motivo. Isso acaba impactando naquele erro.O que eu entendo é que é um dicionário que contém um array de arrays de int64. Cada int64 nos arrays dentro de dict corresponde a um valor de outra variável. Mas eu preciso ordenar isso em ordem decrescente e já tentei de várias formas que deram errado =(

Comment: Entendi bom ai fica complicado, porque da forma que já montei iria precisar passar em uma rotina que vai tirar esse nome (Array) dai, mas não sei se voce poderia fazer issso, por conta de continuação do código..

Comment: Isso funcionou para o que eu queria se colocar 0 no item: {k: v for k, v in sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[0], reverse=True)}

Comment: ótima ideia Patricia! Que bom que funcionou.. desculpe a demora não pude continuar auxiliando ontem